# Why php_user_filter::filter() executed once?

Tags: php

I have a custom filter which must add a value to each string in resource, but the method filter() executed once

```
class custom_filter extends php_user_filter
{
    function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            $bucket->data =  'Test,' . $bucket->data;
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}
```

That how I use this filter class, but only first line has value 'Test'

```
$source = fopen($file, 'rb');
stream_filter_register("custom_filter", "custom_filter");
stream_filter_append($source, "custom_filter", STREAM_FILTER_READ);

while (!feof($source)) {
    $line = fgets($source);
}
fclose($source);
```

How can I add a value 'Test' to each line.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this happens?

Comment: @jchook sorry, I dont remember

Answer (score 0):

The custom `php_user_filter` is executed once, because that entire file is read into a bucket.

```
while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
    var_dump($bucket->data);
    $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
    stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
}

object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["bucket"]=>
  resource(10) of type (userfilter.bucket)
  ["data"]=>
  string(N) "<all data in the file>
"
  ["datalen"]=>
  int(N)
}
```

I suggest to open a separate destination stream for writes and while reading each line of the source stream write to the write stream.

```
stream_filter_register("custom_filter", "custom_filter");
$source = fopen('input.txt', 'rb');
$dest = fopen('output.txt', 'wb');

stream_filter_append($dest, "custom_filter", STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

while (!feof($source)) {
    $line = fgets($source);
    fwrite($dest, $line);
}

fclose($source);
fclose($dest);
```